# ScrollViewer Control in Wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollview

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

The Status always I'm adding to it, that is to say that in the code behind always I do this thing:

```
Status+= Environment.NewLine + "Hi";
```

And the ScrollViewer increasing, but the Status that I see is the first one, when I want to see the last one I need to scroll underneath to see it, my question is: how I can made the Scrollviewer scrolling underneath automaticaly?, that meaning I want always see the last status not the first.

Sorry about the broken english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your ScrollViewer so you can access it in the code behind, like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then you can do this:

```
Status+= Environment.NewLine + "Hi";
MyScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
```

With the way I do MVVM, I have access to my ViewModel from my View, so when the View first loads, I'd subscribe to the PropertyChanged event on my ViewModel as so:

```
MyViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModelChanged;
```

and then in the ViewModelChanged callback I'd have this:

```
private void ViewModelChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Status")
        MyScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

Every time the ViewModel's Status property changes, the ScrollViewer will now scroll to end.  Just remember to unsubscribe from MyViewModel.PropertyChanged when you leave that screen to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, but how I can do this in MVVM pattern?

Comment: In MVVM, the ViewModel is not supposed to know details about the view such as the presence of a ScrollViewer. In cases like this it is widely considered acceptable to write code in the view code-behind to accomplish this task. I'll adjust my answer to show you how I'd do it with MVVM.

Comment: Is this another way to do in xaml?